# Mathematical modeling from gurobipy in pyomo: Define the domain of a concrete model (enumeration, ord,etc.)

Tags: python, constraints, modeling, pyomo, gurobi

I am trying to reformulate a mathematical model from gurobipy to pyomo.I have difficulties with one specific constraint:
I formulated the following code in gurobipy (it all works well):

```
model.addConstrs(
    (quicksum(start[l, i, s, t] for s in SM[n]) <= quicksum(start[l, k, s, T[tau]] for s in SM[D[n]]
                                                            for tau in range(index_t, index_t + dur[n]) if tau < len(T))
     for n in M if n in D for l in LM[n] for index_i, i in enumerate(KM[n]) for index_k, k in enumerate(KM[D[n]])
     for index_t, t in enumerate(T) if index_i == index_k), name='Doppelbelegungskurse')
```

These are the indices:
l-> indice teacher ; n,m->indice coursetype; i,k-> indice course (alias); s-> stations; t,tau->periods.
I have defined different Subsets in form of dictionaries: KM-> Courses k that belong to coursetype n. SM-> Stations that are allowed for course type n. LM: Teachers who can teach course type n. D-> coursetype n that is to be scheduled at the same time as coursetype m. start and gamma are binary variables. start is 1 if course k starts with teacher l in station s at the beginning of period t. dur[n] is the duration in periods of coursetype n. The constraint ensures that when course i starts, course k should be scheduled during course i. The dictionary D is built as follows: D={n1:m1, n2:m2,..}.
I have difficulties in rewriting this constraint in pyomo, especially with the enumerations of the courses and with regard to the subset D in the domain of the restriction.
What I already have:

```
    def doppelbelegung_rule(model, n, l, i, k, t):
    index_t = T.index(t)
    if n in D:
        if l in LM[n]:
            if i in KM[n]:
                index_i = KM[n].index(i)
                print('i', i)
                print('index_i', index_i)
                if k in KM[D[n]]:
                    index_k = KM[D[n]].index(k)
                    print('k', k)
                    print('index_k', index_k)
                    if index_i == index_k:
                        return sum(model.start[l, i, s, t] for s in SM[n]) <=\
                               sum(model.start[l, k, s, T[tau]] for s in SM[D[n]]
                                   for tau in range(index_t, index_t + dur[n]) if tau < len(T))
                    else:
                        return Constraint.Skip
                else:
                    return Constraint.Skip
            else:
                return Constraint.Skip
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip
    model.doppelbelegung = Constraint(M, L, K, K, T, rule=doppelbelegung_rule)
```

Unfortunately this does not work.
I would be really happy if someone could help me to find the problem. Is it also correct to skip the constraints like that in pyomo ? I am totally new when using pyomo ! Further I construct a Concrete model in Pyomo because the data is known beforehand.

Best regards!
Zeineb

Comment: Please ignore the gamma in my question. This variable is not necessary for this equation! :)

Comment: I have a few ideas here, but want to be sure I understand the intent of the constraint...  This constraint will force "compatible" courses to be *started* with some overlap, I think.  What if there is only 1 course of a particular type?  I don't think it would ever be taught....  What if there are 5?  This constraint *could* allow 1 teacher to handle 5 overlapping courses at different start times.

Comment: Also, on your related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73406391/mathematical-modeling-from-gurobipy-to-pyomo-how-to-enumerate-over-a-set-in-pyo, it is customary to "accept" the answer provided by hitting the check mark next to it, if it answered your question, to close out the issue.

Comment: I also think there is a logic problem here.  Course pairings (i, k) and (k, i) cannot both satisfy this constraint if they don't start at **the same** time interval.  `k` cannot overlap the start of `i` and also have `i` overlap the start of `k` unless they start in the same period.

Comment: What is your overall objective here?  There may be another way to do it as this constraint is going to produce a **huge** number of equations.  If you are just trying to be "efficient" with the teacher's time, you could simply sum up the number of periods they are used in, and that will preferentially stack courses in the same time slots, up to any teacher limitation constraint that you might impose...

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and your suggestions! So this is only one constraint of many other constraints in my model. I know that this will potentially increase the runtime but because of some restrictions that I have, i have to model it like that. :) So maybe to explain it a bit better. You can imagine it like this: I have a course x that needs a reservation in a room for its entire duration and at the same time another station booking for a shorter duration.

Comment: So therefore i constructed a course x wich needs to be scheduled in a room and a course x-fictitiouse which needs to be scheduled at the same time as the course x.

Comment: With regard to my data, this all works well because for this case i have only always two courses which have to be scheduled at the same time. And these courses are written down in the constructed subset D.

Comment: and this constraint is only used for this courses that need to have two room bookings. I have other constraints which ensure that every course will start, that a teacher can only teach one course at a time within one period (except of this case with the fictitiouse constructed courses), etc.

Comment: Mathematically, the constraint which i formulated in gurobipy works well. And it does what i want. But i have problems to reformulate this in pyomo-language.

Comment: i hope that my problem description is now clearer. I also think that there are logical problems because of the (i,k) issue. But i don't know how to enumerate it like i did it in gurobipy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I think I understand...  Though to figure parts of this out without any corresponding data.  If this doesn't work below, suggest you update (edit) your orig post and include some (just some) data for all of the elements involved

I think that anytime you are getting into a bunch of `if` statements inside of the construction, it suggests that you should make a better subset *beforehand* instead of trying to weed things out on the fly.  The first suggestion here I think is what you are looking to do, namely within a pair of compatible types, pair up the classes based on index position in a list, and retain reference to the types for purpose of finding instructors and stations...

```
M = {'n1', 'n2', 'n3'}
KM = {  'n1': ['course1', 'course2'],
        'n2': ['course3',],
        'n3': ['course1a', 'course2a']}

D = {'n1':'n3'}

pairings = {(i, k, n, m) for (n, m) in D.items() for (i, k) in zip(KM[n], KM[m]) }

print(pairings)
```

##### Output:

```
{('course2', 'course2a', 'n1', 'n3'), ('course1', 'course1a', 'n1', 'n3')}
```

Then you can just pass that to your initializer function kind of as shown below and you have all the pieces to construct your constraint with the already-paired courses and course types:

```
def dubblebubble(model, i, k, n, m, l, t):
    pass

model.dubblebubble = Constraint(pairings, L, T,rule= dubblebubble)
```

However...  I think there are probably better ways to set this up, unless you are beyond that point.  There seems to be no need for using course types for this pairing process if I understand the problem.  You already know which courses are paired and the "course type" is just unnecessary information causing all of this weird look up and index matching.  Here is a suggestion (I have no idea what form your orig data is in ) that might produce a structure that is easier to work with:

##### Alternate approach:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

# some data
course_types = ['math', 'science', 'english']

#               name        type        duration
all_courses = [ ('math1',   'math',     3),
                ('math2',   'math',     2),
                ('math2-a', 'math',     1),
                ('math3',   'math',     3),
                ('chem',    'science',  2),
                ('chem-a',  'science',  1),
                ('physics', 'science',  3),
                ('reading1','english',  2),
                ('writing1','english',  3),
            ]

sub_courses = { 'math2': 'math2-a',
                'chem' : 'chem-a'}

# model parts...
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

### SETS
m.N                 = pyo.Set(initialize=course_types)
m.all_courses       = pyo.Set(initialize=[t[0] for t in all_courses])
m.primary_courses   = pyo.Set(within=m.all_courses, initialize=m.all_courses-sub_courses.values())
m.course_pairs      = pyo.Set(within=m.all_courses*m.all_courses, initialize=sub_courses.items())

def group_initializer(m, group):
    return [c[0] for c in all_courses if c[1] == group]
m.type_groups       = pyo.Set(m.N, initialize=group_initializer)

# inspect results...
m.primary_courses.pprint()
m.course_pairs.pprint()
m.type_groups.pprint()
```

##### Output:

```
primary_courses : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
    Key  : Dimen : Domain      : Size : Members
    None :     1 : all_courses :    7 : {'math1', 'math2', 'math3', 'chem', 'physics', 'reading1', 'writing1'}
course_pairs : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
    Key  : Dimen : Domain              : Size : Members
    None :     2 : course_pairs_domain :    2 : {('math2', 'math2-a'), ('chem', 'chem-a')}
type_groups : Size=3, Index=N, Ordered=Insertion
    Key     : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
    english :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'reading1', 'writing1'}
       math :     1 :    Any :    4 : {'math1', 'math2', 'math2-a', 'math3'}
    science :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'chem', 'chem-a', 'physics'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I used your first approach ('pairings') and extended pairings with regard to the teacher that is allowed to teach coursetype n!